# notepad++ regex divide two lists

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have below list:

```
21870172299%3Akvm6wcmcVYaoQ2J%3A2   340282366841710300949128111982633033733
21200717504%3AUhGubOhpHPtBKLk%3A6   340282366841710300949128111984034029824
21256096197%3AMGYmtB2uoj4er5i%3A1   340282366841710300949128111984541030820
11665946937%3AHBBkUBzcy3cvbtb%3A5   340282366841710300949128111986242038268
21719881031%3AH3t9c4b7re6cs5%3A24   340282366841710300949128111986284030213
21697692027%3A1S0fM2Jp6Ivsxo9%3A5   340282366841710300949128111986299030036
20424141770%3AFPiScGMuAVBPGvk%3A7   340282366841710300949128111987613032298
```

I would like to use regular expression to divide these 2 list. example:

list1:

```
21870172299%3Akvm6wccVYaoQ2J%3A2
21200717504%3AUhGubOpHPtBKLk%3A6
21256096197%3AMGYmtBuoj4er5i%3A1
11665946937%3AHBBkUBcy3cvbtb%3A5
21719881031%3AH3t9c4b7re6cs5%3A24
21697692027%3A1S0fMJp6Ivsxo9%3A5
20424141770%3AFPiSGMuAVBPGvk%3A7
```

list2:

```
340282366841710300949128111982633033733
340282366841710300949128111984034029824
340282366841710300949128111984541030820
340282366841710300949128111986242038268
340282366841710300949128111986284030213
340282366841710300949128111986299030036
340282366841710300949128111987613032298
```

I have tried to use online regex (regex101) but with failed attempts.

Kindly help me to divide this lists.

Thank you.

Comment: _"I have tried to use online regex (regex101) but with failed attempts"_ Please include your tries [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58637200/edit).

Comment: If they're fixed-width columns as you show in your question, you don't really need regex for this. Just press `Alt` and simultaneously click and drag with your mouse cursor to select the second column. Once it's selected, cut and paste it into your preferred location.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this text and paste twice to your text file, one below the other.

Select first block of data:

[image]

Check "In selection" option and use pattern `(^\S+).+` and replace it `\1` meaning replacing with first capturing group.

Pattern explanation: `^` matches beginning of a string, `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters, `.+` matches one or more of any character, `(...)` means store matched text in first capturing group.

Similarly, select second block of data and use pattern: `^\S+\s+(.+)`

`\s+` matches one or more of whitespaces. Again, check "In selection" check box.